# Set pipeline variables with quotes in Azure Pipelines

Tags: bash, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

On a MS-hosted Azure pipeline running on ubuntu, within a bash script task, I am setting some pipeline variables that need to be available to another task. These variables are oftentimes maps, in the following format:

```
{ "1.0.0" = "my-function-app-url.com" }
```

This will fail the below command, because those maps (stored in the `$VALUE` variable, have double quotes, which will be interpreted at the end of the bash script.

```
echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=$KEY;isOutput=true;issecret=true]$VALUE"
```

I have tried to use single quotes to enclose the string being echoed, but the behaviour is the same. I have also tried to escape the double quotes within the variables, but again, the behaviour is the same! I have even tried to remove the quotes, but then the hashtag symbol is interpreted as a bash comment...

Is there a way to achieve what I want here?

**EDIT:** The problem turned out to be that the string contained newlines. Once that processing was done, all I had to do is to escape the double quotes. Then the code I have shared works just fine.

```
  # If the value is a map... 
  if [[ "$VALUE" == "{"* && "$VALUE" == *"}" ]]; then
    VALUE=$(echo -n "$VALUE" | tr -d '\n')  # Remove the newlines, to inline the value string
    VALUE=$(echo -n "$VALUE" | sed 's/"/\\\"/g') # Escape the double quotes so that the string is a valid JSON string
  fi
```

Comment: Add the quotes with the escape character - `\"`.  Your echo command can be `echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=\"$KEY\";isOutput=true;issecret=true]\"$VALUE\""`. Note that you may need to double the quotes if they are also interpreted by the `setvariable` function.

Comment: I am almost sure I tried that and it didn't work. What I've observed is that, whenever a quote - either double or single - is present, the echo command will finish and everything else will be "dangling". I think because of the "##vso" directive, the normal bash behaviour is being overridden. But let me try again

Comment: @JonathanDodds the command as you wrote it has the same behaviour that I have previously explained. When I doubled the quotes as you suggested, the remaining part of string did not show up dangling like in my previous attempts. However, in the subsequent task, the pipeline variable was not present. Is this the command you had in mind: echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=\""$KEY"\";isOutput=true;issecret=true]\""$VALUE"\""  ?

Comment: What I had in mind was `echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=\"\"$KEY\"\";isOutput=true;issecret=true]\"\"$VALUE\"\""`. For bash, every quote inside the quoted string must be escaped.

Comment: That may not be quite right either. The documentation for [`task.setvariable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/set-variables-scripts?view=azure-devops&tabs=bash) and for [defining variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch) doesn't discuss escaping special characters.

Comment: thank you @JonathanDodds for your help! Turned out that the issue was that the string with the map contained newlines, and also that the double quotes need to be escaped. With that string processing, the initial piece of code that I shared works just fine!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `\` in the definition of your variables. Refer to the following yaml:

```
pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

variables:
- name: VALUE
  value: "\"1.0.0\" = \"my-function-app-url.com\"" 

steps:
- task: Bash@3
  name: setOutput
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: 'echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=ValueWithQuotes;isOutput=true]$VALUE"'

- task: Bash@3
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      echo '$(setOutput.ValueWithQuotes)'
```

In the log of the first bash task, you can see `##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.setvariable variable=ValueWithQuotes;isOutput=true]"1.0.0" = "my-function-app-url.com"` .

The result of the second bash task:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this! As you can imagine, I have no control over the string I am receiving on the pipeline. Therefore I will need to do that parsing before creating the pipeline variable. But indeed, the problem was that the double quotes within the string were not being escaped. That problem was hidden by another problem, which was the newlines within the string. 

I have edited the initial post with that information and with the code that I used to address it. I will mark you answer as the correct one, since you identified the issue and also because you were the first to reply :)

Answer (score 1):

I have code two samples for setVariable with quotes based on above yml. just have a try and hope this can help.

```
pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

variables:
- name: VALUE
  value: '{ "1.0.0" = "my-function-app-url.com" }'

steps:
- task: Bash@3
  name: setOutput
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=ValueWithQuotes;isOutput=true]$VALUE"

- task: Bash@3
  name: setOutput1
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=ValueWithQuotes1;isOutput=true]'$VALUE'"

- task: Bash@3
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      echo '$(setOutput.ValueWithQuotes)'

- task: Bash@3
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      echo '$(setOutput1.ValueWithQuotes1)'
```

below is my two results:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this! Turned out that the issue was that the string with the map contained newlines, and also that the double quotes need to be escaped. With that string processing, the initial piece of code that I shared works just fine! 

I have edited the initial post with the code that I used to solve the issue